# Datetime local 24h format

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use the the 24 hour format in my datetime picker im my view
here the code of my view i am using the simple datetime local

```
<input id="start_date" type="datetime-local" class="form-control>
```

the result:
[image: here's the result]

i tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#clockPicker').timepicker({
      'timeFormat':'H:i'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `class="form-control>`

Comment: And which datepicker are you using?

Comment: What js library are you using for timepicker, you will find option it it documentation for sure

Answer (score 4):

Referring to Mozilla reference, it is NOT possible to choose the date format.

If you want to use 24H format, you can change your system preferences.
The date format is based on your system preferences.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#:~:text=The%20value%20of%20the%20time%20input%20is%20always%20in%2024,always%20hh%3Amm%3Ass%20.

Comment: It is working on chrome under Windows, but it doesn't work on Chromium (Ubuntu).